# Control timeout of system process in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kill, system-calls

I am launching casperJS scripts from my controller as this:

```
output = `casperjs #{path_to_file} '#{url}#'`
```

And sometimes, for several reasons the casperjs script might hang, or might take a long time. I am wondering if there is anyway I can set a timeout in my controller to just kill the process and control it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout.timeout(<seconds>) do
   output = `casperjs #{path_to_file} '#{url}#'`
end
```

This will raise a Timeout::Error exception if the script doesn't finish within the given time

Edit(to kill the process after timeout)

```
require 'timeout'
pipe_cmd_in, pipe_cmd_out = IO.pipe
pid = Process.spawn("casperjs #{path_to_file} '#{url}#'", :out => pipe_cmd_out, :err => pipe_cmd_out)
Timeout.timeout(<seconds>) do
   Process.wait(pid)
   pipe_cmd_out.close
   output = pipe_cmd_in.read;
end
rescue Timeout::Error
   Process.kill('TERM', pid)
end
```

Have a look at the [teminator](https://github.com/jeremyd/terminator) gem as well. It will help if you have many system calls to deal with

Comment: But do I need to kill the script? If so, how? Or it's already killed by the Timeout?

Comment: Vimsha, I assume that the process.wait(pid) is supposed to be Process.wait(pid), right? Also, shouldn't it have a begin somewhere?

Comment: I have another problem with this approach.. I need to store what the script returns into a variable (output). How can I do that with spawn?

Comment: Vimsha, this line: process.wait(pid) -- why is process not uppercase? Process?

Comment: It should be uppercase.

Comment: Vimsha, I also think a begin is missing.